# Native.* assemblyIdentity with Registration-free com

Tags: .net, visual-studio, regfreecom

I set Isolated=true to some COM library that I need to use registration free. Visual studio now created Native.* manifest files for each of my assemblies:

1. Why "Native"? Can I change this? Can someone point me to info I can read? (googling native / assembly / manifest  is yield a lot of non-related info )
2. Is there a way I can embed these manifest files into the assembly DLL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can embed the manifest using the SDK tools.  There are some examples and instructions here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx

Not sure if you can change the default auto-generated name, but if you're going to embed it anyway I'd be asking myself do I really care what it's called?